# Is it okay to pass a HOC via React context?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a task to create a new React component in an existing project. The project is composed from several sub-projects. Two of them are:

- `WebApp`: contains the most of application logic, Redux store, and "smart" React components connected to the Redux store.
- `Design`: contains "dumb" React components which are styled and can have their own local state.

One of the project rules says that `Design` components can be imported into `WebApp`, but not vice versa. So in case if a "dumb" component needs to fire a store action, one of the "smart" components have to expose the action with `mapDispatchToProps`, and pass it all the way down to the "dumb" component.

The problem with my new component is that it can be used in many places of the project, sometimes pretty deep in a chain of "dumb" components. So, in case if I follow the project rules, I will have to update a lot of "dumb" components with all the new properties that my component should receive.

To avoid this, I tried to use a HOC-like "smart" component, and pass it via React context to my "dumb" component. I say "HOC-like" because it's not a classic HOC, but a one that uses [render property](https://medium.com/@sgobinda007/using-reactjs-hoc-pattern-be-aware-of-the-side-effects-f52beae77703).

My "smart" component from `WebApp`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MySmartComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.render({
          someAction: this.props.someAction,
        })}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  someAction: payload => {
    /* something happens*/
  },
});

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(MySmartComponent);
```

My "dumb" component from `Design`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export const MyContext = React.createContext({});

class MyDumbComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        {({ MySmartComponent }) => {
          return (
            <MySmartComponent
              render={({ someAction }) => (
                <>/* someAction can be used here */</>
              )}
            />
          );
        }}
      </MyContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDumbComponent;
```

And then I provide `MySmartComponent` as context in some of the root components in `WebApp`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MyContext } from 'Design/MyDumbComponent';
import MySmartComponent from 'WebApp/MySmartComponent';

const myContext = { MySmartComponent };

class SomeRootComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      /* ... */
      <MyContext.Provider value={myContext}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
      /* ... */
    );
  }
}

export default SomeRootComponent;
```

I suspect that this can be a misuse of React context. Or maybe it's just a bad practice? But then, what could be the downsides?

Comment: If it can be done,it will be an overkill. Have you tried it though?

Comment: So, you want to create a `smart ` component that exposes actions to your dumb component?

Comment: @humanbean, yes, i tried and it works. And this is what scares me the most 

Comment: @F.bernal, yes, this is what I try to do.